# How do I index a (not all ascii) utf8 string in C?

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8

I want to index the characters in a utf8 string which does not necessarily contain
only ascii characters. I want the same kind of behavior I get in javascript:

```
> str = "lλך" // i.e. Latin ell, Greek lambda, Hebrew lamedh
'lλך'
> str[0]
'l'
> str[1]
'λ'
> str[2]
'ך'
```

Following the advice of [UTF-8 Everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/#faq.literal), I am representing my mixed character-length string just as any other sting in c - and not using wchars.

The problem is that, in C, one cannot access the 16th *character* of a string: only the 16th *byte*. Because `λ` is encoded with two *bytes* in utf-8, I have to access the 16th and 17th bytes of the string in order to print out one `λ`.

For reference, the output of:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                    

int main () {                                                                                                         
  char word_with_greek[] = "this is lambda:_λ";                                                                       
  printf("%s\n",word_with_greek);                                                                                     
  printf("The 0th character is: %c\n", word_with_greek[0]);                                                           
  printf("The 15th character is: %c\n",word_with_greek[15]);                                                          
  printf("The 16th character is: %c%c\n",word_with_greek[16],word_with_greek[17]);                                    
  return 0;                                                                                                           
}
```

is:

```
this is lambda:_λ
The 0th character is: t
The 15th character is: _
The 16th character is: λ
```

Is there an easy way to break up the string into *characters*? It does not seem too difficult to write a function which breaks a string into wchars- but I imagine that someone has already written this yet I cannot find it.

Comment: `which breaks a string into wchars` Don't. Just don't. wchars are __not__ _decoded_ UTF-8 characters. wchars are another encoding. If you want to/need to decode, then decode to a utf32 string.

Comment: Just about everything about Unicode is non-trivial. So I suggest you try to find a library (there are a few) to help you. Asking for libraries if off-topic here though, but you could try on [the software recommendation stack exchange site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Your question is slightly contradicting. You state that you want to *iterate* through a string. That's a very natural concept for UTF-8. You have a pointer into the string and a function that tells you how many bytes to skip to get to the next character. But then you want to access the 16th character. That's *indexed access* - not iterating. Check your requirements again. Indexed access is usually not needed. Most likely it's just an old habit of how you have implemented string processing in the past.

Comment: @Codo may you expand your explanation? Why you may want to `iterate` over a string if it is not for processing it, which is probably this processing requires `accesing` the chars? I am missing your point...

Comment: Iteration is for string processing. But iteration doesn't need an index. The index of the character to process is usually irrelevant. You just want to access the character at the iterator's current position. Indexed access is inefficient with Unicode (see Schlemiel the painter's Algorithm), iteration with the concept of a current position is fast.

Comment: There is no fast and easy definition of *character*. Is oᷔ a single character? Why or why not? How about o͡e, how many are there?

Comment: You enter in a very difficult field. What is a character, a word, a line, etc. Unicode appendix have (IIRC) some algorithms, and the standard, in every script, has some script specific note. First: you should decode the string (working directly with an encoding is difficult). But then you should combine all combining code points. But then you have specific script issues (think about cursive scripts). Tip: treat all opaquely. Use word split algorithm. Go to character only for specific scripts (that allow breaking words, or special initial, or...). It is not something to handle generically

Comment: See: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/tr29-33.html: Unicode Text Segmentation: *This annex describes guidelines for determining default segmentation boundaries between certain significant text elements: **grapheme clusters (“user-perceived characters”)**, words, and sentences. For line boundaries, see [UAX14] . *

Comment: Iterating over UTF-8 byte sequences is easy...iterating over user-perceived characters is much harder.  For the former, UTF-8 intermediate bytes always start with the bit pattern `10xxxxxx`, so for example `while((*p++ & 0xC0) == 0x80);` will advance to the next lead byte.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your unicode characters can be. Most strings are restricted to the [Basic Multilanguage Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane). If yours are (not by accident by because of their very nature: at least no risk for emoji...) you can use the `char16_t` to represent any character. BTW `wchar_t` is at least as large as `char16_t` so *in that case* it is safe to use it.

If your script can contain emoji character, or other characters not in the BMP or simply if you are unsure, the only foolproof way is to convert everything to `char32_t` because any unicode character (at least in 2019...) as a code using less than 32 bits.

Converting for UTF8 to 32 (or 16) bits unicode is not that hard, and can be coded by hand, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) contains enough information for it. But you will find tons of library where this is already coded and tested, mainly the excellent libiconv, but the C11 version of the C standard library contains functions for UTF8 conversions. Not as nice but useable.

Comment: 16-bit unicode has the same flaws as utf8, just less often,

Comment: For compatibility with UTF16 all unicode can fit in 24 bits.  32bits will always be enough.

Comment: @Jasen: C standard defines no char type for 24 bits :-)

Comment: @SergeBallesta: But a code point is also not enough. E.g. combining characters: they should never be at start of a new string (so they cannot be as "second character" of the question). Semantic is in any case outside standard C.

Comment: yeah, chars, code-points, and glyphs are three different measures of character.